# Android Get all supported deeplinks of an app programmatically

Tags: android, deep-linking

Is there any way to get all the supported deeplinks in an app through PackageInfo or any other way programmatically? I know that we can get list of activities (ActivityInfo) but how can I get the deeplinks supported by those activities?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Please specify the reason for downvotes, so that I can improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompile an APK and take a look at `AndroidManifest.xml`, you will see the full list of intent filters for each of the activities. So I think you could try to retrieve and parse the manifest file inside your app with code to generate a list of links.